# Can I find the end effector position from joint velocities?

Tags: jacobian

I would like to know if I can find the end effector position according to joint velocities. I have found joint velocities of a manipulator. I need to check if it is correct. So I need to know that how can I combine joints veloties and the end effector postion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Oğuz KAHRAMAN, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot determine the end effector position by using only joint velocities.  If you use the Jacobian matrix, you can determine the velocity vector of the end effector given a set of joint velocities.  If you have a finite time over which the joint velocities were measured, you can know how much the end effector has moved in that short time.  But unless you have a starting position, the joint velocities are insufficient for determining end effector position.

However, if you do know the forward kinematics as well as the joint velocities, you can use $\dot{x} = \mathrm{J} \dot{\theta}$ to determine incremental end effector motion.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I know the starting position of the end effector via forward kinematic and I also know the interval time. How can I compute the end effector movements in this finite time ?

Comment: Oğuz, please modify the original question with this additional information.  Without it, both of @SteveO's questions are correct, yet conflicting.

Comment: Thanks @Ben.  I tried to clear it up with a single answer.